# Word VBA, is there a reason why this does work under Word 2003 Win XP but not Word 2007 Win 7

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a macro which works in Word 2003 running on Win XP, the macro is in normal.dot template the relevant part is below. It is run from a merged .rtf, copies the current document, opens a new document, pastes in the copied content along with some data from  userform combos, saves it in a custom named file, and closes it out leaving the user back where they started. It then goes on to FTP the saved document. It works as expected.

```
ActiveDocument.Content.Copy
Documents.Add
ActiveDocument.Content.Paste

'Add the data from the Userform
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
 .ClearFormatting
 .Text = "\<refDestination\>*\<End Synapse data\>"
 .Replacement.ClearFormatting
 .Forward = True
 .Format = False
 .MatchCase = False
 .MatchWholeWord = False
 .MatchWildcards = True
 .Replacement.Text = "<refDestination>" & ComboBox1 & "</refDestination>" & _
                     "<refType>" & ComboBox2 & "</refType>" & _
                     "<End Synapse data>"
 .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, _
  Wrap:=wdFindContinue
End With


ActiveDocument.SaveAs savedName, wdFormatDocument
ActiveDocument.Close ' Now go on to FTP savedName

MsgBox "wait here"
```

I am trying to run the same macro on a different site on Win 7 and Word 2007 and it fails, I cannot delete savedName as it is already open, in some way activedocument.close does not release the file, and the process hangs. If I use task manager to force word to close I can then go to the file at savedName and open it fine and it contains the right data, it just seems to stall on closing.

Comment: Why are you showing us the code that works, but not the part where the process hangs (the ftp part)?

Comment: Because the FTP part is not the issue. If I put in MsgBox at the end then try try to delete savedName file it throws a file locked error.

Comment: On Windows 7 I have seen such effects. But the culprit wasn't Word (or Excel in my case), but the File Explorer with its file preview on the right-hand side of the window. Does your file happen to be displayed there?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot explain why your macro worked on the Windows XP/Office 2003 platform and why it runs into an error on the new platform. But I see that you're using the ActiveDocument object for two different documents, the source and the destination. During copy, Word creates temporary files (see [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/211632/en-us) in MSDN, see "Text Pasted Between Files").
I'm unsure if there's a connection, but I'd rather use two different objects, e.g.

```
Dim docSource as Word.Document
Dim docDest as Word.Document
Set docSource = ActiveDocument
docSource.Content.Copy
Set docDest = Documents.Add
docDest.Content.Paste
docSource.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
<continue with docDest>
```

Comment: its a good idea and thanks but it didn't fix the problem.